# Proof of residual sum of squares formula

Tags: statistics

"Consider the standard model:

$$
Y = X \beta + \epsilon
$$

where $X$ is the $n \times p$ matrix of rank $p$, $\beta$ is vector of $p$ unknown parameters and $\epsilon$ is a random vector whose components are independent normal random variables, each with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. For the least squares estimator $\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$ of $\beta$, denote the vector of residuals by $r = Y - X \hat{\beta}$. Show that the residual sum of squares fulfills:

$$
r^Tr = Y^TY - Y^TX \hat{\beta}.
$$""

How do I go about doing this. I managed to prove that $X^TR = 0$ but I'm not really sure what to do from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
  r^\top r &= Y^\top Y - Y^\top X\hat \beta + \hat\beta^\top X^\top r
\end{align*}
Now 
\begin{align*}
  X^\top r &= X^\top Y - X^\top X \hat \beta\\
    &= X^\top Y - X^\top X \hat \beta\\
    &= X^\top Y - X^\top X (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y\\
    &= 0
\end{align*}
Hence from the above
\begin{align*}
  r^\top r &= Y^\top Y - Y^\top X\hat \beta + \hat\beta^\top X^\top r = Y^\top Y - Y^\top X\hat \beta
\end{align*}

Comment: Why do you have the $+\hat{\beta}^TX^Tr$ in the first equation? Where does that come from?

Comment: We have $r = Y - X\hat \beta$, so $r^\top = Y^\top -\hat\beta^\top X^\top$ and hence $r^\top r = Y^\top (Y - X\hat\beta) - \hat\beta^\top X^\top r$.